# "Inside of" a state/country & "my life/the summer" (time period), and "One of the worst English"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

My friend recently said this and it just sounded wrong to me, but I don't know why:

"Despite having grown up **inside of Ohio**, he's a guy who has one of the worst English I've ever met **inside of my life**."

It would be very funny and ironic if he were using English wrong here, but I've tried looking it up and I don't see any rules regarding "inside of my life" vs "in my life" or "inside of Ohio" vs "in Ohio".

"One of the worst English" sounds a little funny, but I'm pretty sure it's correct.

Comment: Sounds like your friend needs a little time in Ohio himself.

Comment: *has one of the worst English* might be the reddest flag here...

Comment: Yeah, I missed that one myself :( I'm still learning!
"You must unlearn what you have learned." - Yoda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Inside of (a state)*" is correct and often used. "*Inside of my life*" is technically correct but an uncommon usage. Normally we would say "*in my life*".

The incorrect grammar in that sentence is the phrase "*One of the worst English*". "*of the worst English*" is plural so the word that it is modifying should also be plural. A possible correction would be: "*some of the worst English*".

Comment: Neither of those is idiomatic in my dialect or any North American dialect I've heard of. I'm curious what dialect of English you speak?

Comment: United States, whatever dialect is most common, I think? I'm from Northern California, but my friend is kind of from a "skater" background, so that might have contributed :) We're both Korean-Americans, and I hadn't heard these phrases either until he used them recently. I get the feeling he just spends a lot of time around people who are worse in grammar than he is, whether they have an accent or not.